# how to change list contains as user is typing?

Tags: html, django, ajax, jinja2

I have input and `datalist` like this.

```
<input list="BrandTitle" name="BrandTitle">
<datalist id="BrandTitle">
      {% for item in brand_list %}
          <option value="{{item.Title}}">
      {% endfor %}
</datalist>
```

Now I want when I type something I get this on the server-side and send it to SOAP web services. and make brand_list from webservice response.
I want to change the brand_list as the user is typing!

for example when user type 'a' list shows:

'Apple'
'Facebook'
'Amazon'

and when type 'ap' shows :

'Apple'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic way of doing this is using pure javascript without using any framework.
See the following code :

```
    <input name="BrandTitle" list="BrandTitle" onkeyup="autoccomplete(this.value)" >
<datalist id="BrandTitle">
      {% for item in brand_list %}
          <option value="{{item.Title}}">
      {% endfor %}
</datalist>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
    var brandTitle = [  
    "Amazon", 
    "Apple", 
    "facebook" 
     ];
     var n= brandTitle.length;

     function autocomplete(value) 
     { 
        document.getElementById('BrandTitle').innerHTML = ''; 
        l=value.length; 
        for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) 
        { 
         if(((brandTitle[i].toLowerCase()).indexOf(value.toLowerCase()))>-1) 
         { 
             var newOption = document.createElement("option"); 
             var value = document.createTextNode(brandTitle[i]); 
              node.appendChild(value); 

               document.getElementById("BrandTitle").appendChild(newOption); 
             } 
         } 
     } 

</script>
```

Hope this will help you